# Which of these two Java codes is faster?

Tags: java, memory-management, heap-memory

Both theoratically and practically which code is faster:

```
class ABC{
    File file;

    void method(){   
        file = new File();
    }
}
```

or

```
class ABC{

    void method(){
        File file = new File();
    }
}
```

where class ABC is instantiated only once. But the `method()` for that instance is called multiple times. Note: I KNOW the speed actually is irrelevant in this case.

Comment: This code does nothing of consequence in either case. You will be hard pressed to measure the time accurately, never mind a difference.

Comment: If you need the file to be an instance field, make it an instance field. If you only need it in that method, use a local variable. The speed is irrelevant.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak what do you think is faster- adding a new reference at the end of the heap-memory every time (2nd code) or scanning location of where a reference (that was created in past) exists every time (1st code)?

Comment: You're confused. The two codes make new inside of the method, so the two codes add a new object in the heap. The only thing that differ is where is stored the variable that references this object. One stores it along with the other data of an object instance, and the other stores it on the stack. That's both memory, so both essentially the same speed in general.

Comment: @kumesana I was not asking about the time it takes to access instance of File in each case. I was asking only about the time it takes to execute method() when it is called multiple times.

Comment: You were describing two different behaviors you thought the two different approaches would have. They don't have these different behaviors.

Answer (score 4):

The performance difference is unlikely to matter much.

In the first version , there will be a valid reference to the `File` object around until the next call to `method`, but the previous object will still need to be garbage-collected after it got replaced. In the second version, the `File` object is orphaned the moment `method` is finished and can be garbage-collected.

So the first version means you will always have at least one non-collectable `File` object staying around in memory as long as the instance of `ABC` exists. This is unlikely to be much of a problem, though, unless `File` consumes a non-negligible amount of memory (it only contains the path and name of the file. Buffering file content is `BufferedReader`'s job) and you keep a lot of `ABC` instances around.

What you should be worrying about, though, is code clarity. The general rule is that every variable should have the smallest scope possible. When it *can* be a local variable, then it *should* be local variable. The reason is that the smaller the scope, the less code might possibly affect its value, which makes the application easier to debug. When you encounter a bug where `file` suddenly hasn't got the value you expect it to have, you only need to examine that one method, not the whole class.

Answer (score 0):

At last I got a direction. Not on stackoverflow but on Quora. Check the answer by Cameron Purdy here..https://www.quora.com/How-much-time-does-it-take-to-access-an-object-and-variable-in-Java-And-whats-the-ratio-between-them

Comment: 1. this does not seem to be the same question as asked here, 2. answers on stackoverflow should provide the answer themselves, not just link to other websites which provide an answer. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers